# How do i download images from Airtable and upload to Wordpress using Airtable and Wordpress APIs preferably in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, automation, airtable

Im looking to make an automation script that takes images from Airtable and downloads and upload them to Wordpress upload folder. these images should backfill on all the post types with the empty image fields i have created for them. for example say i made a profile for myself James Major and there is an image field, it should take that pic and fill in it. i don't have a clue where to begin as I'm new to coding and i am learning on the fly. thank you for your help

```
enter code here
```

````
var base = new Airtable({ apiKey: 'API KEY HERE' }).base('Base key here');

const table = base('USERS');

const getRecords = async() => {
    const records = await table.select({
        maxRecords: 0,
        view: "Website Export"
    }).firstPage();
    console.log(records);
};
getRecords();
const getRecordById = async(id) => {
    try {
        const record = await table.find(id);
        console.log(record)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

// const createRecord
getRecordById(); ```
````

Comment: any update on this ? I am looking for image download option too from airtable